# WxWidgets App build Error Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets

I built a wxwidgets c ++ program with visual studio 2019, on my pc there were no problems, but when i tried to start it on another pc i got a missing libraries message. I searched the internet and was advised to change the code generation settings from DLLMultiThread (/ MD) to MultiThread (/ MT), I re-built the project and got several error messages like:

```
**1> wxbase31u.lib (string.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (thread.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (list.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (appbase.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (time.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (hashmap.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (object.obj): error LNK2038: found mismatch for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (strconv.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (log.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (event.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (stringimpl.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (strvararg.obj): error LNK2038: found mismatch for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (unichar.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (stringops.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (intl.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (wxcrt.obj): error LNK2038: found mismatch for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (xlocale.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (dummy.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (module.obj): error LNK2038: found mismatch for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (msgout.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (translation.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (utils.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (main.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (threadinfo.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (arrstr.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (config.obj): error LNK2038: mismatch found for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' does not match 'MT_StaticRelease' in Window.obj**

**1> wxbase31u.lib (stdpbase.obj): error LNK2038: found mismatch for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease'**
```

(maybe these are not exactly the warnings because I had to translate them from my language):

what am i doing wrong? I can not understand.

Comment: ***what am i doing wrong?*** Using the wrong value of the runtime. The advice you were given to change MD to MT was bad advice in that your would have to recompile wxWidgets to match this also.

Comment: Then how can I fix this problem or the missing libraries problem (libraries like MSVC140.dll and VCRUNTIME140.dll)?

Comment: The simplest way is to install the visual studio redistributable. For my applications I create a NSIS based installer that does that automatically along with my applications and data. The redistributable can be downloaded here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Comment: @TheNemoNemesis, what was the original error message you received? Now as Vasdim said linking the CRT statically is not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose between linking the standard C++ (CRT) libraries dynamically or statically. If you link them dynamically, which is the default, and almost always a better, choice, you need to distribute the DLLs that your executable depends on with your application and make sure they can be found in the same directory where you install it. If you link statically, using `/MT`, you must build your application and all its dependencies, including wxWidgets, using the same option too. For wxWidgets this can be done when building using makefiles from the command line by passing `RUNTIME_LIBS=static` on `nmake` command line. If you use the project files, you will have to manually check the `RuntimeLibrary` option for all of them (which can be done by multi-selecting them in the IDE and modifying this option for all configurations and platforms).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try all the methods you have advised me