# How do I correctly compile wxWidgets with VS Code and MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I am currently working on developing a GUI front-end for a console-based C++ application using wxWidgets (I decided against dancing with Qt's licensing conditions). I've been doing all the work for this app thus far in VS Code, so I tried my hand at adapting the instructions detailed in the provided *docs/msw/install.md* file, with no luck. As kind of a reference point, I'm trying to compile the "Hello World" example code on wxWidget's website [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) (copy-pasted into my own file). Whenever I try to compile, I get a slew of LNK2019 and LNK2001 errors (literally hundreds of them). Here's the first 3 for reference:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@YAXPBDH000@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall wxEventFunctorMethod<class wxEventTypeTag<class wxCommandEvent>,class MyFrame,class wxCommandEvent,class MyFrame>::wxEventFunctorMethod<class wxEventTypeTag<class wxCommandEvent>,class MyFrame,class wxCommandEvent,class MyFrame>(void (__thiscall MyFrame::*)(class wxCommandEvent &),class MyFrame *)" (??0?$wxEventFunctorMethod@V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCommandEvent@@@@VMyFrame@@VwxCommandEvent@@V2@@@QAE@P8MyFrame@@AEXAAVwxCommandEvent@@@ZPAV1@@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct wxPrivate::UntypedBufferData * __cdecl wxPrivate::GetUntypedNullData(void)" (?GetUntypedNullData@wxPrivate@@YAPAUUntypedBufferData@1@XZ) referenced in function "protected: static struct wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<char>::Data * __cdecl wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<char>::GetNullData(void)" (?GetNullData@?$wxScopedCharTypeBuffer@D@@KAPAUData@1@XZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class wxMBConv * __cdecl wxGet_wxConvLibcPtr(void)" (?wxGet_wxConvLibcPtr@@YAPAVwxMBConv@@XZ) referenced in function "class wxMBConv & __cdecl wxGet_wxConvLibc(void)" (?wxGet_wxConvLibc@@YAAAVwxMBConv@@XZ)
```

Ending with (directory censored):

```
...\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 339 unresolved externals
```

I have tried searching for any clues as to how I should go about doing this, but any resources I find seems to be either for GCC or Visual Studio or just downright not the issue I'm having. So, my question is, what is the "correct" way to compile wxWidgets apps in VS Code and the MSVC (cl.exe) compiler? How should I have the include and linker paths set up in the compiler flags? And are there any preprocessor directives that I'm just straightup missing?

This is how I currently have my compiler options set up:

*tasks.json*

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "/IC:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\lib\\vc_lib\\mswu",
                "/IC:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\include",
                "${file}",
                "/link",
                "/LIBPATH:C:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\lib\\vc_lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "cmd.exe",
                "args": [
                    "/C",
                    "\"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat\"",
                    "&&"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*c_cpp_properties.json*

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include",
                "C:/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/vc_lib/mswu"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "NDEBUG"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Admittedly these files are a little sloppily put-together. They're just retrofitted relics from old one-off projects, but up till now they've served their purpose pretty well. To my knowledge, the include paths and library path in *tasks.json* should be correct, but this is my first time using wxWidgets (be gentle) and I have pretty limited experience with playing around with MSVC flags directly. Any adjustments I try to make to the paths produce different errors (obviously), like not being able to find *wxbase32u.lib*, but I'm under the impression that's fixable by... well... actually using the correct paths. From here, I'm pretty well stuck.

I did compile my own binaries per the instructions, both debug and release (side note: I am in fact trying to use release binaries here), and I did successfully compile and run the "minimal" sample code provided with the wxWidgets source, so I'm pretty sure the binaries themselves are not problematic. I tried disecting the Makefile used for the sample for hints, but the formatting admittedly mystifies me, and I'd be even at more of a loss trying to refactor that into VS Code's configurations.

Now, I do realize that I could fairly easily, with just a little bit of time, migrate my app development to Visual Studio or figure out how to put everything into a Makefile or use GCC, but I'm going to try to make this an opportunity to learn a little bit about the linker. So, if say someone were unable to use any editor/compiler combo besides VS Code and cl.exe, or just too stubborn to switch to something else, how could they go about doing it?

Comment: I believe you need to pass the `.lib`s for wxWidgets to the linker? And I think VSC has nothing to do with the problem, you can run the same command in the terminal.

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/MSVC_Setup_Guide#Project_Settings

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Downloading_and_installing_wxWidgets

Comment: @kiner_shah, please do not suggest to follow WiKi instructions. Find more reliable and up-to-date onee.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbauch, VSC is just an editor. I presume you are using MSVC with it, so why not use the full-blown IDE? Anyway, if you can open minimal sample in the MSVC and look at its properties to find what path is used and then used in your own project....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Correct, but--correct me if I'm wrong--I believe I accomplished this by passing `/link /LIBPATH:C:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\lib\\vc_lib` to MSVC.

Comment: @Igor Like I pointed out in the original post, I know just using VS is an option, but I'd like to learn how the command line works as well, and a I feel this question could be useful for people who can't use VS for some reason. And, as I also said in the original post, I did already try looking at the minimal sample for direction, and besides the fact that the formatting has me a little confused in some places, I think I have the paths correct.

Comment: @kiner_shah The wiki has been pretty unhelpful... all of the detailed instructions are for Visual Studio. But, when I looked at it again today, I did notice something that may or may not help. If it does, I'll update the post.

Comment: @Igor, how do you know the Wiki's outdated? Do you already know link to a newer documentation?

Comment: @kiner_shah, it's WiKi. Anybody can post anything. There is no time stamp on when the last edit occurred. Now I don't know about VSCode, but for MSVC everything is easy and straightforward.

Comment: Also MSVC is supported out of the box, while VSCode you will need to go thru some hoops to make it work. Check the minimal sample on how to set CMake build thing. Maybe it will give you some clues.

Comment: @Igor I was already anticipating it would take some work to get it going in VSCode, I've used both it and the Visual Studio IDE. Also to prevent misunderstanding, unless I am mistaken, MSVC refers to the compiler itself (`cl.exe`), which both VSCode and Visual Studio use (i.e., VSCode is by technicality "supported", it just takes some work translating IDE setup options to command-line flags). And, as I've said before, I already checked the minimal example with limited luck, and in the end, it ended up not helping.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, yes, except VSC is not actually IDE - it just an editor. MSVC is actually an IDE. WHat you need to do is to open minimal sample inside MSVC and look at the `include` and `library` paths of the project properties. Then use them inside the VSC project.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, now for your answer, You first problem is not actually a problem, The path is correct - at that path lies the build specific header file callsed setup.h. This file has to be included in addition to the second one. Now you additional `include` path is incorrect and it has to be `c:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\include\` in addition to `c:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\lib\vc_lib\mswu`. The point of using `/MD` I already explained.

Comment: @Igor The paths were, in fact, incorrect for my setup. It worked after I made that change. If you read the instructions provided by wxWidgets, the paths I changed it to are the paths needed. Taken directly from the instructions:
- Add `$WXWIN/include` to the include paths.
- If using MSVC, prepend `$WXWIN\include\msvc` to the include paths too.
- Add `<wx-lib-dir>` directory described above to the libraries path.
I'm assuming the other path would be correct if I were using a compiler like GCC or Clang instead of MSVC.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, you ae missing the point here. The instruction you quoted says `add` not `replace`. Moreover - if you open minimal sample wxN.sln - you will never see the path you are talking about. The headers located inside include\msvc are private to the library and never should be included directly in the build or in the code. The only 2 include patjhs are - ${WXWIN}\include and ${WXWIN}\lib\vc_{lib,dll}\. Nothing more, nothing less. Try it - if you get the error building it, post it here. But I'm positive you will not.

Comment: @Igor It does say "add", not "replace", because those instructions are assuming a blank slate for an include paths list (with respect to wxWidgets), there is nothing to replace. I do not have a `wxN.sln` file for the minimal sample. The only .sln files present for the minimal sample are `minimal_vc*.sln` files, none of which contain any direct reference to include paths whatsoever.

Comment: @Igor And I did run it with just `$WXWIN/include` and `$WXWIN/lib/vc_lib`, and I did get an error: `C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\include\wx/platform.h(159): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/setup.h': No such file or directory`.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, that file is located inside `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib` directory. That is if you build the library yourself. One more time - open the minimal sample sln file inside the MSVC and you will see tht there are 2 include directories that are needed. And when you build the sample - it will build and run fine.

Comment: @Igor I know that a `wx/setup.h` exists in the library directory (specifically in the `mswu[d]` subdirectories), but considering I get a different C1083 error if that particular file is missing: `C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\include\msvc\wx/setup.h(142): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../../../lib/vc_lib/mswu/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory` I'd wager that file is not the file in question from the previous C1083 error, i.e., the only other `wx/setup.h` it could be looking for that I know of off the top of my head is the one under `$WXWIN/include/msvc`.

Comment: @Igor Also, I repeat myself: none of the .sln files for the minimal sample directly contain any include paths. However, after another scan over the wxWidgets-provided install instructions, I took another look at the `wxwidgets.props` file, which contains necessary data for setting up wxWidgets in an existing VS project. This file does contain include paths, and it does include both `$WXWIN/include` and `$WXWIN/include/msvc` when the MSVC compiler is used.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, `none of the .sln files for the minimal sample directly contain any include paths.`. I want to see it to believe it. Open MSVC, open the minimal.sln from the distribution, right click on the minimal, go to properties, select C/C++ and then select "General" and the look at the "Additional Include Directories". You will see 2 additional directories, separated by semicolon. Now there they will be relative. All you need to do is to make them direct.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, and I don't know what instructions did you look at that says you should add the directory you did add. But that directory is wrong. Copy the Include path from the place I pointed to you and place it in the project you made replacing anything there is right now and make those paths direct. Then you project will compile and link successfully. Also, don't forget to rebuild everything with the static linking (if you really, really, really need to).

Comment: @Igor I apologize for a slight misunderstanding on my part with the .sln files, I was opening them in a text editor to read the raw data in the file (which *doesn't* have the paths) instead of in Visual Studio to process them first. [Here are the instructions I am working from](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.2.2.1/docs/msw/install.md#building-applications-using-wxwidgets--msw_build_apps), the actual installation markup doc straight from wxWidgets' official Git repo.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, nowhere in that instruction I found the directory you tried to add. One more time - open minimal sample solution and check the additional include directory property. Use MSVC and not text editor. Then fix your own project. And of course - make sure you follow instructions in the docs and not blindly try to fix something.

Comment: @Igor With all due respect, I don't know how you don't see the path. It is part of the second bullet point under the "Building Applications" section (in line 468 of the raw data from the markdown file). I am following instructions, and after following the instructions you gave me (open the .sln in Visual Studio), I see there are, in fact, only the two include paths for the minimal sample--the ones you are talking about--and when I try to build it... fatal error C1083, exactly the same as the first error I had (`cannot open include file: 'wx/setup.h'`), no modifications to the provided project.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, can you build `minimal` sample from MSVC solution? And run it? And when you copy those 2 into you own project and `adjust it`, you get the error you mention? Can you confirm there is in fact setup.h file present inside wxWidgets `lib` folder somewhere?

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, also, out of curiosity - how did you build wxWidgets? With MSVC and provided solutions? Or you used Command Prompt from MSVC? Did you change the solution? Which exact command you used?

Comment: @Igor I cannot build the sample from the Visual Studio solution, that is what produces the error I mentioned. And yes, there is a `setup.h` file in the `lib` directory (in the `mswu[d]` subfolders). I built wxWidgets with the command prompt using the command `nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=release` (following [this section of the instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.2.2.1/docs/msw/install.md#from-the-command-line), and I can use this command to successfully build the minimal sample as well), no modifications were made to any wxWidgets source code.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, good, when you successfully build `minimal` sample from command prompt - keep an eye on the `-I` directive it uses when running the compiler. Also - keep in mind that building the library and the sample or you code HAS TO BE DONE with exactly the same set of options.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, I'm sure that there will be only 2 set of directories used when you building minimal sample `$(WXWIN)\include` where all necessary header files areand `$(WXWIN)\lib\mswu`, where the setup.h file is located. No where you will find a private `$(WXWIN)\include\msvc` directory included during the build.

Comment: @Igor I am aware that building the library and the sample requires the same parameters. It does use `include` and `lib/mswu` instead of `include` and `include\msvc`, which is interesting. Though, obviously there has to be some other difference besides include paths between the overall setup of the minimal sample compared to my code.

Comment: @Igor I also see that the minimal sample's makefile uses a number of other parameters (in particular, preprocessor definitions and a reference to `sample.rc`) which my code does not use. I suspect those other parameters make up the difference, but I need to do some testing to figure out exactly how. Granted I am not new to the programming scene (I've been coding for several years now), this is the first time I've messed with wxWidgets, so I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of the library to know for sure off the top of my head.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, nothing else plays a role here. Try to build the sample exactly the same way you built the library and look what commands are generated for building. Then update your VSC project settings accordingly and rebuild.

Comment: @Igor I tried what you said, and after spending some time testing different flags, I tracked down what I think is happening. As I suspected, it was the other parameters, specifically the [`/c` flag (compile without linking)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-compile-without-linking?view=msvc-170) and the usage of `link`, which to my understanding explicitly compiles to a .obj file first before conversion to .exe. Removing the flag produces exactly the same error I expect.

Comment: @Igor Changing my compiler options to match just feels like extra steps. I imagine it is a nicety for the minimal sample, considering it requires linking to more external files, but in the case of my code which is largely self-contained--proper procedure or not--it seems like extra work for an identical result, i.e., not worth it for code of this scale.

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, the `minimal` sample is called `minimal` for a reason. Nothing is linked in it except the windows run-time and wx base and core libraries..

Comment: @TaylorGrossenbacher, also you are definitely wrong - the directory you included should be private to the library and there is no guarantee that they will continue to work. One more time - use settings from the minimal sample. Otherwise with every single update to wx, you will have to check if something changed or broken and keep fixing stuff that shouldn't be broken in the first place. That include/msvc folder shouldn't even be there. It should be inside include/wx/msw.

Comment: @Igor By "external files", I was referring to the `sample.rc` and related files that are not exclusive to the minimal sample nor part of the wxWidgets libraries. And I apologize, but I will be blunt and admit that I have been taking what you are saying about `include/msvc` with a grain of salt. Should the need for me to change the settings arise, I will. But it is contradictory to say it shouldn't be there or be used, since it is there, `install.md` explicitly says to use it, and it is in `wxwidgets.props`, all of which can be seen in the official repository. If you explain this, I will cede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back to this with a fresh mindset in the morning, I found my problem. Well, I actually had a couple problems. For everybody else's reference, I'm leaving the original post unmodified.

First and foremost, the problem that actually started this post: I had a major typo in *tasks.json*. The include path that leads to `C:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\lib\\vc_lib\\mswu` should be `C:\\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\\include\\msvc`. That wasn't me misunderstanding the setup instructions for wxWidgets, that was just me being tired and hand-typing that path in a few dozen times instead of just copy-pasting.

But, that generated a new set of errors on top of the LNK2019/2001 errors, namely LNK4286, LNK4217, and (most importantly) a bunch of LNK2038 errors:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary' : value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
```

Took me 5 seconds to add `/MD` to the flags in *tasks.json*, and now it compiles perfectly fine now.

Now, why the linker is expecting a dynamic release and not a static release even though I'm using static libraries, I have no clue. I moved the final .exe around on my computer and obfuscated the library path with no runtime issues, as far as I know, it behaves like a statically-linked library. So, if anyone who knows why the linker is behaving like this, feel free to comment. In the meantime, since I was able to solve my problem, I'm accepting this as the answer.

Comment: the issue is that you only build wxWidgets for static linking. Run-time should be built as dynamic one as this is strongly recommended by MS. If you want everything to be static - you should prepare to build multiple copies of you binaries for different Windows versions and deal with MS for violating their recommendations should any issues arise.

Comment: That's why wxWidgets is always built with dynamic run'time linking despite how the library itself is built.

Comment: @Igor I want this project built using static linking, that isn't a mistake. I'm aware of the stipulations of both, and static linking more readily satisfies my requirements. And to my knowledge, it's perfectly possible to build wxWidgets using static linking (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703432/wxwidgets-app-build-error-visual-studio-2019) thread is actually about the same discrepancy between /MD and /MT, and I think the point it brings up about standard C++ libraries is more in line with the issue I am having).

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done. But you misinterpret the building and linking of wxWidgets with linking the CRT. The `/MD` vs `/MT` flags controls the linking of CRT and BY DEFAULT wxWidgets builds are using the dynamic linking of CRT as strongly recommended by MS. If you want to change it - fine, but you should be aware of implications it can cause. That's the point I tried to make. One more time don't confuse the CRT with how wxWidgets itself is built and can be linked.

Comment: I don't know and I don't care what specific requirements you have that prevents you from lionk CRT dynamically - I'm sure you have your own reason. I just wanted to point out that you will have to build multiple executable especially if you want to support older Windows version.  And I also want to point out that *nix/Mac standard way of building is to use dynamic linking of EVERYTHING.

Comment: Now the last point I want to make is that if you yuorself are creating a DLL - you better use dynamic build of everything to prevent multiple copies of different wxWidgets and or CRT libraries to be loaded at the same time. Or have multiple copies of wxWidgets to reside in memory wasting its space.

Comment: @Igor I am fully aware of the consequences of everything being statically linked, the pros/cons of both static and dynamic linkage. And I see what you are saying now about the CRT. It's on my to-do list to rebuild wxWidgets to accommodate that, it's just not pressing at the current phase of my project.

Comment: keep in mind that it is essential to build the library AND your application with EXACTLY THE SAME settings. Otherwise you will be susceptible to some weird behavior. So I suggest to do that now, while you still remember.